# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end - can someone explain

Tags: php, syntax-error

The error I am getting with my code below is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

The HTML CODE:

```
<form style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; text-align:center;" action="contactus.php" method="post">
                <label for="name">
                    Namn/F&ouml;retag
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Skriv in erat namn/f&ouml;retag h&auml;r">
                    </label><br>
                     <label for="email">
                    E-mail
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Skriv in erat namn/f&ouml;retag h&auml;r">
                    </label><br>

                    <label for="amne">
                    &Auml;mne
                    <input type="text" name="amne" placeholder="Skriv in &auml;mnet h&auml;r">
                    </label><br>

                   <label for="message">
                    Meddelande
                       <br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Skriv in meddelandet h&auml;r" rows="20" cols="70">
                       </textarea><br>
                       <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
                    </label><br>

                </form>
```

The PHP SCRIPT:

```
 <?php

    $emailSubject = $_POST['amne'];
    $webMaster = $_POST['info@example.com'];

    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $amneField = $_POST['amne'];
    $messageField = $_POST['message'];

    $body = <<<EOD
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    Namn: $name <br>
    E-mail: $email <br>
    Amne: $amne <br><br>
    Meddelande: $message <br>

    EOD;

    $headers = "Fran: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

    echo = "Ditt meddelande har skickats";
?>
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "Nonsense becuase stackoverflow won't let me post: blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla"

Comment: Pay attention to details

Comment: Try removing the space before the end of the HEREDOC ( EOD; ) that needs to be on its own line with no space before or after.  Because it's not it doesn't see the end to the text block.

Comment: Try replacing every line of your code with a different one.

Comment: ^ not try ^ => **do**. Read => http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few things wrong here; the heredoc and this `$headers = "Fran: $email\r\n";`

I believe that `Fran` in your language which looks to be Swedish, means "from".

But with [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) - PHP, the syntax remains the same in any given spoken language, therefore it must be and read as `From:` in the headers, so I've fixed that in the code below also.

By just fixing the heredoc syntax only, the mail's header would not register a proper "From" address and would have most likely end up in, and marked as Spam.

*As for the heredoc:*

There shouldn't be any spaces, or **anything at all** (including tabs, or any hidden characters such as *unicode etc. <= see footnotes) surrounding the [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) delimeters.

Here, and copy it exactly as shown:

```
<?php

$emailSubject = $_POST['amne'];
$webMaster = $_POST['info@example.com'];

$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$amneField = $_POST['amne'];
$messageField = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br>
<hr>
<br>
Namn: $name <br>
E-mail: $email <br>
Amne: $amne <br><br>
Meddelande: $message <br>

EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

    echo "Ditt meddelande har skickats";
?>
```

Sidenote (edit): There shouldn't be an equal sign in:

```
echo = "Ditt meddelande har skickats";
     ^ remove it
```

I thought I had fixed that too.

---

Read up on heredoc:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc**

---

**Footnotes:**

*About unicode characters: Some unicode characters can sometimes be found/accidentally/unknowingly embedded and virtually undetected, so be careful/watchful for those also, because that will also cause heredoc to fail. I have seen this happen before.

Although this isn't the case here, you should be made aware of it, should an unexpected similar error occur in the future and you cannot see the hidden unicode.

However, these codes can be seen by IDE's / code editors.

Comment: This helped, But I still got error, that was because "=" after echo, @mike helped me with that, Thanks to both of you guys!

Comment: @SwegreDesigns You're welcome. I'm just glad it got resolved, *cheers*

Comment: @SwegreDesigns Silly me, I thought I had fixed/gotten rid of the `=` sign. Oh well, no problemo. So, about that `Fran:`? Did you fix that too?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that this statement:

```
EOD;
```

does not have any whitespace in front of it. It looks like you have the code indented and that is allowing for that whitespace in front of EOD

Also, although you didn't ask, you'll also need to change from this:

```
echo = "Ditt meddelande har skickats"
```

to this:

```
echo "Ditt meddelande har skickats";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two faults, one of them maybe caused by Stackoverflow's textarea:

1. No indentation can be before or after ending HEREDOC (`EOD;`)
2. you have `=` after `echo` in the last row, it should be `echo "Ditt meddelande har skickats";`

Comment: *"No indentation can be before ending HEREDOC"* - "**or**" after; *technically speaking*. ;-)

Comment: Plus, there's (what I believe to be) an undocumented rule that there should be at least a carriage return under the delimiter if there is no code after it; otherwise, it will also cause a parse error. Another thing, there shouldn't be spaces before the starting delimeter `$body = <<<EOD` which OP's code contains.